# Clearing app data - what happens with running application instance?

Tags: android

My application is using SQLite for some of its Activities. For example, there is one with a list which are rows of a certain table. Now, when this activity is shown, and I go to the app information and push the 'Clear data' button, the database is removed. Coming back to the application and clicking anything on the list would most likely crash.

This doesn't happen - I can't come back to the application as it is no more listed in the recents view, and starting it new read the database new. Is this always guaranteed to happen? I'm using Lollipop and this is my only test device for now, and I'm not sure what would happen in previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clear the data, the system kills your application before, so yes it's guaranteed.

Comment: Is there any resource which documents this behavior?